# lowlevellock: robust_lock_wait function not found

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, inline-assembly

I downloaded and compiled the  header which is used in pthread functions. But one function is missing and that is *__lll_robust_lock_wait*. Now I noticed that there is an assembly code header out there, . I downloaded this and tried to compile it using the usual the compile command "as lowlevelrobustlock.S" and I got nearly 100 compiler errors. Is there a simpler version of the function I mentioned that will actually compile and be useful?

The assembly code header can be found [**here**](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/plain/libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i486/lowlevelrobustlock.S)

Comment: Make sure you use a header file that actually goes with the library you're using (same version, same platform, same options).. preferably the one that actually came with the library from your system.  Then make sure you've got pthreads enabled through your compiler options and that you link to the right libraries.

Comment: Where could I get the pthread source code library?

Comment: On linux, you *might* need to install a pthread development package, although pthreads is part of glibc.  On Windows, try pthreads-win32 at http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ .  This sort of library relies on the underlying operating system so the internals of the library will be different for different platforms.

Comment: Dimitri, I was able to get the lowlevellock functions to compile by copy-n-paste to gcc inline assembly code. There is a site which has all the pthread function source code and you can check it out here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=d0ce23d37e9b77d6ff82ffdee0f7a1f8f137aa41;hb=HEAD

Comment: That's the great think about Linux! It's 0PEN S0URCE. So when you're missing functions you can find the source code, add them to the header, and then compile. ;-)

Comment: ...as long as you respect the licenses.  And it's risky to mix and match bits and pieces from different versions of a library.  Even if the API stays the same the internals may differ which can create problems if you mix parts from different implementations... so you should *at least* get all the parts from the same place.